# Project Reactor: Wait for list of Mono's to complete

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm expecting for the code to wait for the Mono's to complete and then to collect the results, but it never happens.

Why?

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Mono<Integer> mono1 = Mono.fromCallable(() -> 1);
        Mono<Integer> mono2 = Mono.fromCallable(() -> 2);
        List<Mono<Integer>> monos = Arrays.asList(mono1, mono2);

        Mono
                .when(monos)
                .subscribe(__ -> {
                    int i1 = mono1.block();
                    int i2 = mono1.block();

                    System.out.println(i1 + i2);
                });

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
```

Comment: blocking inside the subscribe should never be required, and is an antipattern. you actually trigger the callables multiple times by doing this (once by the when, once by the block). `when` is about waiting for completion, disregarding elements and their types. `zip` would allow you to combine the values of several *valued* monos. But from your other comments it seems you're after something even more different.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Mono.when()` call is of type `Mono<Void>` - it just completes (or errors, if one of its publishers returns an error.) There's thus never an element emitted, therefore never a call to `subscribe()`, therefore the code in that subscribe block never executes.

It's not clear exactly what you want to happen here, but the quickest "fix" could be to `materialize()` before subscribing, so you get the `onComplete()` signal propagated as an element:

```
Mono
        .when(monos)
        .materialize()
        .subscribe(__ -> {
            int i1 = mono1.block();
            int i2 = mono1.block();

            System.out.println(i1 + i2);
        });
```

Note this will print `2`, not `3` because both `i1` and `i2` are referencing `mono1`.

Comment: I have a `Flux<IN>`. I'd like to map it to a `Flux<List<OUT>>` where every `OUT` is a product of some `Function<IN, OUT>`. And, I'd like to do it asynchronously. That is, we wait for all the functions to complete and collect it to a list of `OUT`s.

Comment: I should have present in the question - sorry.

Comment: @yaseco Do you meant map to a `Mono<List<OUT>>`? If you genuinely want to map a `Flux<IN>` to a `Flux<List<OUT>>` then you'd need to specify windowing details (what elements go in the first list, what go in the second, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I meant `Flux<List<OUT>`. The order isn't important for me - Would that make it easier?

Comment: @yaseco No, the issue is the windowing. Say I have a Flux<IN> that emits integers 1-10, and a "doubler" function. How should that map to Flux<List<OUT>>? A single list of 2-20? One list of 2-14, another with 16-20? 10 different lists, all containing one integer? That needs to be well-defined in your question.

Comment: It will map to `[2], [4], [6], ... [20]`. If we had "doubler" and "+1" it will be mapped to: `[2, 2], [4, 3], [6, 4] ... [20, 11]`. So in general, `IN` is being transformed to `[f_1(IN), ...f_n(IN)]`

Comment: @yaseco Understood, so the function is actually a `Function<IN, List<OUT>>`?

Comment: Yes, but. The idea is that you're given a `Function<IN, OUT>[]` (predefined and constant) and each function is ran separately (i.e. executed from some `Scheduler`). So after this operation we're left with a `Flux<List<OUT>>`

Comment: `Flux<IN>.map(FUNCTION).collectList()` will do the trick, reactively applying the function to each input element and adding the result to a single list that is emitted when the source completes